# Finding $a$ such that $y_1=\frac{a}{2}x+\frac{1}{2}$ and $y_2=-\frac{3}{a}x+\frac{1}{a}$ are orthogonal. Impossible?

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus, orthogonality

> For which values of $a$ are the two lines orthogonal?
> $$y_1=\frac{a}{2}x+\frac{1}{2} $$
> $$y_2=\frac{-3}{a}x+\frac1a $$

The criterium for two lines to be orthogonal, is that the product of their slopes equals $-1$.

$$\frac{a}{2} \cdot \frac{-3}{a}=-1 $$
$$\frac{-3}{2}=-1$$
When I do the calculation I get an anomalous result. Does this mean that there really is no value for $a$ such that the lines are orthogonal to each other?

Comment: These two lines are essentially non-orthogonal.

Comment: Yes.${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: The only possible exception is $a=\infty$ or $a=0$, in which case one line is horizontal and the other is vertical. But that requires playing fast-and-loose with these definitions of the lines.

Comment: Yes,  Those lines are never orthogonal.  There's no reason to think that as their slopes are both dependent on the same variable that it should be possible that they are orthogonal soo we shouldn't be surprised when we discover that they can not be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$y=\frac{a}{2}x+\frac{1}{2} $$
$$y=-\frac{3}{a}x+\frac1a $$
slopes are $$m_1=\frac{a}{2};\;m_2=-\frac{3}{a}$$

As $$m_1\cdot m_2=\left(\frac{a}{2}\right)\left(-\frac{3}{a}\right)=-\frac{3}{2}\ne -1$$ there is no value of $a$ such that the two values are perpendicular.

This is not an "anomalous" result. Your work was correct and your conclusion was right.